# Display a value id in ajax from the php page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My code does not display value from my-page.php , [Live demo](http://www.varzesht.com/live/select/index2.php) ,Also I want to defult show the `selected` value

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $loading = $('#loading');
  var $content = $("#content");

  $("#select123").change(function() {
    $loading.fadeIn();
    var value = this.value;
    $content.fadeOut(500, function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'my-page.php',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
          var $target = $(html).find('#' + value);
          $loading.fadeOut();
          $content.append($target).fadeIn();
        }
      });
    });
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<select id="select123">
  <option value="content1" selected>content1</option>
  <option value="content2">content2</option>
  <option value="content3">content3</option>
  <option value="content4">content4</option>
</select>
<div id="content"></div>

<div id="progressbar">
  <span id="loading"></span>
  <div id="load">loading...</div>
</div>
```

my-page.php

```html
<body id="monica">
  <div id="content1" class="content123">
    text defult show
  </div>
  <div id="content2" class="content123">
    contentttttttt
  </div>
  <div id="content3" class="content123">
    content3
  </div>
  <div id="content4" class="content123">
    content4
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Check the console for errors. There are hundreds of reasons an AJAX request could fail.

Comment: Thank you, `console.log($target)` , see the [link](http://www.varzesht.com/live/select/index2.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a root tag around the html text returned from the server and apply the selector afterwards:

```
var appendedHtml = $('#' + $('#select123').val(), $.parseHTML('<div>' + html + '</div>')).html()
$content.html(appendedHtml).fadeIn();
```

Comment: Opens only # content4 and adds a number in the text every time! See the [Link](http://www.varzesht.com/live/select/index2.php)

Comment: you would have to set "#content4" to the value selected in the dropdown (`'#' + $('#select123').val()`). If you don't want to append but replace the string in #content each time you select, use `$content.html(appendedHtml).fadeIn();`

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect these changes

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work! Please see [demo live](http://www.varzesht.com/live/select/index2.php) ، Thank you for your support. Selected in first option. Iwant append to #content

Comment: You didn't use the whole two lines above in your code. You're missing the parseHTML piece. Paste the two lines in your success function and it should work. Comment out the rest of the function by now.

Comment: I'm wrong, sorry. Your answer was correct. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Simple way can be to use a javaScript function like this way

```
<select id="select123" onchange="update_content();">
```